# IF statement with multiple answers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to make a table and c4 will be radius required and the minimum weight for that radius requirement will be in `D4`

The chart is;

```
   radius      quantity
0,040 - 0,06 :    33 
0,061 - 0,10 :    67 
0,101 - 0,20 :   100
0,201 - 0,50 :   333
```

so when I type in the radius to `C4`; it will tell me the minimum quantity (just as number) to produce. As an example: for `0,4` it should say `333`; for `0,055` it should say `33`
What I typed in is below:

```
=IF(0,04<=C4<=0,06;33;IF(0,061<=C4<=0,10;67;IF(0,101<=C4<=0,20;100;IF(0,201<=C4<=0,50;333;IF(0,501<=C4<=0,80;500;IF(0,801<=C4<=1,50;1000;IF(1,501<=C4<=2,20;1667;IF(2,201<=C4<=4,00;2500;))))))))
```

but it always comes as 0.

Comment: Please go over your question and add more detail, as it is the question is too hard to understand. Explain what you've tried so far, what version of Excel you're using. In the meantime, if you want to enter a radius and get a weight you may want to research VLOOKUPs instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have more than one condition in your if statement. "0,04<=C4<=0,06" is two conditions. Instead, use an AND statement to break it up like:

```
IF(AND(0,04<=C4; C4<=0,06); 33; IF...
```

I'm also a bit unsure about the overall syntax (using semicolons as seperators and having numbers that look like "0,04"), but I'm from the US and it could just be correct for whatever language/locale you are using. So probably no worries there.